# Recursion Solution to Flea Fractal Task

Tags: javascript, recursion, canvas, fractals

I'm trying to solve task 9.3 from book "Think Recursively by Eric S. Roberts (1986)". 
Let consider that we have simple triangle:

```
              .
             / \
            /   \
           /     \
          /       \
         /         \
        /           \
       /             \
      /               \
     /                 \
    /                   \
   /                     \
  /_______________________\
```

Putting a smaller flea on each of two segments that forms the back of the large flea gives the next stage:

```
              .
             / \
            /   \
           /     \
 _________/       \_________
 \       /         \       /
  \     /           \     /
   \   /             \   /
    \ /               \ /
     /                 \
    /                   \
   /                     \
  /_______________________\
```

Each of these two new fleas plays host to two smaller fleas, which give us the following menagerie:

```
              .
             / \
            /   \
     .     /     \     .
 ___/_\___/       \___/_\___
 \       /         \       /
  :     /           \     :
 /_\   /             \   /_\
    \ /               \ /
     /                 \
    /                   \
   /                     \
  /_______________________\
```

The problem is that I can not figure out the recursion pattern here. I even do not know how should I start to think about this task to find a solution.

For drawing I use 3 functions:

1. setPointer(x, y) -- sets the pen to coords x,y
2. vector(dx,dy) -- draw line from x, y to dx, dy
3. polarVec(l, angle) draw line from x, y with length l by angle (in degrees)

My class for drawing at Canvas:

```
        var X_CENTER = 400;
        var Y_CENTER = 400;
        function DrawLib() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var inverted_y = 800; 
            var _dx = 0, _dy = 800;

            this.setPoint = function (x, y) {
                inverted_y = 800;
                inverted_y -= y;
                _dx = x;
                _dy = inverted_y;
                ctx.moveTo(x, inverted_y);
            };
            this.vector = function(dx, dy) {
                _dx += dx;
                _dy -= dy;
                ctx.lineTo(_dx, _dy); 
            };
            this.polarVec = function(lengthPx, angle) {
                var radians = angle * Math.PI / 180;
                this.vector(lengthPx * Math.cos(radians), lengthPx * Math.sin(radians));
            }
            this.stroke = function () {
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        }

        var drawLib = new DrawLib();
```

My solution (perfectly works only for order 0 and 1):

```
        function fractLine(order, l, theta) {
            if (order == 0) return drawLib.polarVec(l, theta);
            fractLine(order - 1, 2 * l/3,theta);
            fractLine(order - 1, l/3,theta - 120);
            fractLine(order - 1, l/3,theta + 120);
            fractLine(order - 1,  2* l/3,theta);
        }

        function triangleWithFleas(order, l) {
            //left side of triangle
            drawLib.setPoint(X_CENTER - l/2, Y_CENTER - Math.sqrt(3)* l/4);
            //start drawing
            drawLib.vector(l,0);
            fractLine(order, l, 120);
            fractLine(order, l, 240);
            drawLib.stroke();
        }

        triangleWithFleas(1, 400);
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier if you only think in terms of `polarVec()`? You need a function that draws a triangle at a particular orientation from a particular starting point. Then, it recursively calls itself twice, adjusting the orientation and starting point for each call.

Comment: @jxh thank you for your replay! I added code to my question. It works only for order 0 and 1. I can not spot where is my mistake. Could you take a look?

Comment: @jxh just updated my code. Now it perfectly works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

According to @jxh comment, I needed a function that draws a triangle at a particular orientation from a particular starting point. Then, it should recursively calls itself twice, adjusting the orientation and starting point for each call.

I've updated my code. `triangle` draws the triangle, `showFlake` recursively draws the flea triangles after calling `triangle`.

Now it works perfectly.

```
var X_CENTER = 400;
    var Y_CENTER = 400;
    function DrawLib() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var inverted_y = 800; 
        var _dx = 0, _dy = 800;

        this.setPoint = function (x, y) {
            inverted_y = 800;
            inverted_y -= y;
            _dx = x;
            _dy = inverted_y;
            ctx.moveTo(x, inverted_y);
        };
        this.vector = function(dx, dy) {
            _dx += dx;
            _dy -= dy;
            ctx.lineTo(_dx, _dy);
            return {
                x: _dx,
                y: 800 - _dy // coord inversion
            };
        };
        this.polarVec = function(lengthPx, angle, color) {
            var radians = angle * Math.PI / 180;
            return this.vector(lengthPx * Math.cos(radians), lengthPx * Math.sin(radians));
        }
        this.stroke = function () {
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }

    var drawLib = new DrawLib();


    function triangle(x, y, l, theta) {
        drawLib.setPoint(x, y);
        drawLib.polarVec(l, theta);
        var firstAngle = theta + 120;
        var secondAngle = theta + 240;

        var firstTrianleStartPoint = drawLib.polarVec(2 * l / 3, firstAngle);
        drawLib.polarVec( l / 3, firstAngle);

        var secondTrianleStartPoint = drawLib.polarVec(2 * l / 3, secondAngle);
        drawLib.polarVec(l / 3, secondAngle);

         return {
            x1: firstTrianleStartPoint.x,
            y1: firstTrianleStartPoint.y,
            x2: secondTrianleStartPoint.x,
            y2: secondTrianleStartPoint.y,
        }
    }

    function showFlake(order, x, y, l, theta) {
        if(order === 0) return;

        var coords = triangle(x, y, l, theta);
        showFlake(order - 1, coords.x1, coords.y1, l / 3, theta + -60);
        showFlake(order - 1, coords.x2, coords.y2, l / 3, theta + 60);
    }

    var len = 600
    var x = X_CENTER - len / 2;
    var y = Y_CENTER - Math.sqrt(3) * len / 4;

    showFlake(5, x, y, len, 0);
    drawLib.stroke();
```